# Execute function with complex parameters

Tags: javascript, .net, jurassic

For a not relevant reason for this question, i need to call a javascript function, defined  inside a js file, from a .net desktop application and get the result.

I'm using Jurassic to do this. However i don't know how to call functions which recieve complex types. Is more simple to explain using an example.

I have this js file

```
function plus(a, b) {
    return a + b;
}
```

Then, for call this function on .net, i use this code:

```
    Dim auxfile As New Jurassic.FileScriptSource(pathToPreviosJSFile)
    Dim aux As New Jurassic.ScriptEngine
    aux.Evaluate(auxfile)
    Dim suma As Integer = aux.Evaluate("plus(2,3)")
```

At this point suma = 5. However if the definition of plus function was

```
function plus(a, b) {
    return a.value + b.value;
}
```

How should i call plus function to get the same result?

Comment: blind guess: `Dim suma As Integer = aux.Evaluate("plus({value:2},{value:3})")`

Comment: @WolfgangKluge Perfect. That's the solution. Thanks for the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are calling value property of `a` and `b` means a and b are objects.
so you can call that function as

```
Dim suma As Integer = aux.Evaluate("plus({value:2},{value:3})")
```

Comment: Perfect. That's the solution. Thanks for the help. I will mark it as accepted answer in 10 minutes :)